# How do I make this select in Single query?

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to select two (comma separated) items, one for "cuisines" and other one is for "facilities" from 4 tables in mysql.

This is how I tried it:

```
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS cuisines,
                 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS facilities
          FROM cuisines c, facilities f
            INNER JOIN restaurant_cuisines rc ON rc.cuisine_id = c.id   
            INNER JOIN restaurant_facilities rf ON rf.facility_id = f.id    
          WHERE rc.restaurant_id = 16 AND rf.restaurant_id = 16";
```

But this query is not working. But if I use two separate query for this two selection then I can get it to work. But I am looking for a solution in single query.

This is the output if I use two separate query:

```
mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS cuisines
    -> FROM cuisines c
    -> INNER JOIN restaurant_cuisines rc ON rc.cuisine_id = c.id
    -> WHERE rc.restaurant_id = 15;
+-----------------------------------------+
| cuisines                                |
+-----------------------------------------+
| American, Asian, Bars & Pubs, Beverages |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.14 sec)
```

Can anybody tell me is it possible in mysql?

Thank you.

Comment: please update with the output you want ( and input for the restaurant 16 in both tables )

Comment: @amdixon, updated my question. Yes `restaurant_id` is same for both table.

Comment: your query is mixing , notation and inner join notation.  which is why you get the error pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `,` and `inner join` notation in a from clause  They are two separate standards (ANSI vs non-ANSI) the compiler has to pick and use one, it can't use both.  in other words...

```
FROM cuisines c, <-- This isn't allowed with inner join syntax.. 
     facilities f
INNER JOIN restaurant_cuisines rc ON rc.cuisine_id = c.id   
INNER JOIN restaurant_facilities rf ON rf.facility_id = f.id
```

I've altered the order of the joins so that cuisines --> restraunt_Cusines-->restraunt_facilities-->facility.  I believe this to be accurate based on the notation and joins.  I've also eliminated one of the where clause criteria as it is now redundant based on the joins created.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS cuisines,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS facilities
FROM cuisines c
INNER JOIN restaurant_cuisines rc 
  ON rc.cuisine_id = c.id   
INNER JOIN restaurant_facilities rf 
  ON rc.restraunt_Id = Rf.restraunt_ID
INNER JOIN facilities f
  ON rf.facility_id = f.id    
WHERE rc.restaurant_id = 16;
```

or

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS cuisines,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS facilities
FROM cuisines c
    ,facilities f
    , restaurant_cuisines rc 
    , restaurant_facilities rf  
WHERE rc.restaurant_id = 16 
  AND rf.restaurant_id = 16
  AND rc.cuisine_id = c.id   
  AND rf.facility_id = f.id
```

However I believe you're missing a join between restaurant_cuisines and restaurant_facility, likely on restaurant_Id which would allow you to eliminate of of the two `rc.restaurant_id = 16 
      AND rf.restaurant_id = 16`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a GROUP BY statement for it to have effect:

```
SELECT cuisines,facilities FROM (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS cuisines, restaurant_id
      FROM cuisines c
        INNER JOIN restaurant_cuisines rc ON rc.cuisine_id = c.id   
      WHERE rc.restaurant_id = 16) a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS facilities,restaurant_id
      FROM facilities f
        INNER JOIN restaurant_facilities rf ON rf.facility_id = f.id    
      WHERE rf.restaurant_id = 16
      GROUP BY rf.restaurant_id) b ON a.restaurant_id=b.restaurant_id;
```

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'facilities' in 'field list'

Comment: sorry, did not finish the query. See edit in 1 minute

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'c.name' in 'field list'

Comment: Try again :) Copy/paste issue

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a.restaurant_id' in 'on clause'